# What is the general identity of this summation:

Tags: summation

$$\sum_{i=1}^n n$$

I am confused by the solution to this question:
$$\sum_{x=0}^{n-2} 4n=4n(n-1)$$

I know by the distributive property, the 4 can be moved in front of the summation. However, plugging $k=(n-2)$ in $k(k+1)/2$ doesn't return the correct answer and c*k isn't correct either.

What generic form does the summation in the problem take that got that answer?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Sum of a constant (e.g., $n$, which does not depend on the index) is the constant times the number of terms

Comment: You are confusing $$\sum_{x=0}^{n-2}4n$$ with $$\sum_{x=0}^{n-2}4x.$$ The latter is $$0+4+8+\dots+4(n-2),$$ but the former is $$4n+4n+\dots +4n,$$ where you have $n-1$ terms of the same value.

Comment: So $$\sum_{i=1}^n i=1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}2,$$ but $$\sum_{i=1}^n n=n+n+\cdots+n=n^2.$$

Comment: I see, so it is "n + n", n-2 times?

I don't know how to embed summations but if this is just the summation of a constant, shouldn't the answer be n(n-2)? Because it's c*n where c = n and n=n-2?

Comment: The summation is starting from 0, not 1.  So there is an extra value, and it is $n-1$ and not $n-2$.

Comment: I see, I was confused because I thought summation from 0 and from 1 were always the same thing. Is that only in the case where the summation is dependent on i?